# Laravel: How to check user auth for API routes without middleware('auth:api')

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-passport, laravel-api

how can i check if the current user accessing a method from a controller is authenticated,
the API route in question is not guarded by any authentication middle, because the route is accessible to public and both guest users, i checked my request headers the Bearer token is being passed, am using a react router for my routes. and api driver is `passport`

**public route**:

`Route::get('product/list', 'ProductController@index')`

**what've tried**:

1. Changed the default AUTH Guard to `api`.
2. Tried Explicitly calling the `Auth()->guard('api')->check()` in the controller method.

```
    if (Auth()->guard('api')->check()) {
          return 'is_favourite';
    } else {
          return 'unauthenticated';
    }
```

3. also called it like this `Auth()->check()`

```
    if (Auth()->check()) {
          return 'is_favourite';
    } else {
          return 'unauthenticated';
    }
```

**Result**:

Always `'unauthenticated'`

Expected Results: result of `is_favourite` when a Bearer token is pass in the header, and 'unauthenticated' if no bearer token is supplied.

Comment: `Auth::guard('api')->check()` ?

Comment: Are you sure the Bearer token you are passing in the testing request is correct?

Comment: @gbalduzzi yes it is it is been used in other routes that has the `middleware('auth:api')` set directly

Answer (score 7):

I finaly got it to work, tried with this and it worked:

```
if (auth('api')->check()) {
      return 'is_favourite';
    } else {
      return 'unauthenticated';
    }
```

Comment: It's worked in laravel 8, I can now call the same api (outside auth middleware) with and without auth token, with different response for each :)